# How to use the SCIM API war file

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to extend some features to the scim api that are not supported.

I've added the following maven dependencies from WSO2 Nexus repository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.inbound.provisioning.scim</groupId>
    <artifactId>identity-inbound-provisioning-scim</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.inbound.provisioning.scim</groupId>
   <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provide</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <type>war</type>
   <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I've identified that I need to change the `org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.resources.SCIMUserManager` (and its UserStoreManager), and also add a new endpoint in the `org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.resources.UserFeature`.

However, these are located within `org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider` but it seems that the war dependency hasn't any classes attached (and the maven 'classifier' tag is in vain), therefore I can't import or inherit those classes.

So, how can I extend the SCIM Api by using the `org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider` library but managed by Maven?

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your question well. Anyway, You can change scim endpoint (wso2.war) file and put into repository/deployment/server/webapp directory. Also, you can find the class inside WEB-INF directory.

Comment: I've updated the question. I would like to use your maven repository instead of having to add manually the files.